# World Wind Java fails to retrieve WMS resources

Tags: java, worldwind

I've downloaded the WorldWindJava SDK and run the HelloWorldWind example. However I get the following error every time:

> Oct 21, 2016 2:16:48 PM
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheRetrievalPostProcessor run SEVERE:
>   Retrieval failed for
>   http://worldwind20.arc.nasa.gov/mapcache?EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0
>   Oct 21, 2016 2:16:48 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtils
>   retrieveSessionData SEVERE: Exception while retrieving resources for
>   http://worldwind20.arc.nasa.gov/mapcache?EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.HTTPRetriever.doRead(HTTPRetriever.java:48)
>     at
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever.read(URLRetriever.java:368)
>     at
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever.call(URLRetriever.java:244)
>     at gov.nasa.worldwind.retrieve.URLRetriever.call(URLRetriever.java:1)
>     at
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtils.retrieveSessionData(SessionCacheUtils.java:80)
>     at
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtils.getOrRetrieveSessionCapabilities(SessionCacheUtils.java:170)
>     at
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicTiledImageLayer.retrieveResources(BasicTiledImageLayer.java:723)
>     at
>   gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.BasicTiledImageLayer$2.run(BasicTiledImageLayer.java:812)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Needless to say, the application fails to render any WMS layer.

I've tried to navigate to the URL using a browser but the connection times out.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue or work around it?

Comment: Assuming your internet connections is ok... if the request times out in the browser you either have the URL wrong, you need additional info in your request (certificates, authentication, etc) or the server is just down/broken. The URL seems odd to me. Whey would you have EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml ? that seems like a format not an exception.

Comment: I just googled and found this and it worked for me: http://worldwind25.arc.nasa.gov/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had nothing to do with the formatting of the URL, it fetches it from a configuration file which is as downloaded. Do you suggest I change the URL do the one you have provided?

Comment: What exactly did you google? Your URL points to a different server?

Comment: I googled nasa wms arc

Comment: @Maps In worldwind you can changes default layers and urls. To do this see following link https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/index.html?gov/nasa/worldwind/Configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Use http://data.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/ instead of http://worldwind20.arc.nasa.gov - that's the actual URL. The URL you have must be one of the specific servers in the cluster.

So your full URL would be http://data.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/mapcache?EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0